# Printing Selected Lines in Large File

Tags: awk

I am new to AWK.

I have a large text file (>3GB). Like to use AWK line command to extract/print selected lines (line #62, #152 and 153) in that order and it iterates every 217 lines till end of record in file.

Tried to search and learn from the net. Tried the below and it does not seem working,

```
awk '{(for (i=62; i<=NR; i=i+217)||for (i=62; i<=NR; i=i+217)||for (i=62; i<=NR; i=i+217)); print}' file.txt
```

and

```
count=62||152||153
awk '{if (++count%217==0) print;}' file.txt
```

Could you assist to give me some pointers or lead me to any web which might be of help.

I am using this http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/awk1line.txt to learn.

rgds
Saravanan K

**Update #1 - 21 Sept 2012 - 10.40pm**

Tried

```
awk 'NR == 62 || NR == 152 || NR == 153 || NR % 217 == 0 {print $0;}' file.txt
```

Able to print line #62, #152 and #153 but not all the following iterations e.g #(62+217), #(152+217) and #(153+217) and so on.

Tried the below too, but it is not working well.

```
awk '(NR == 62 || NR == 152 || NR == 153) && (((NR-62) % 217==0) || ((NR-152) % 217 ==0)|| ((NR-153) % 217==0)) {print $0;}' file.txt
```

**Update #2 - 21 Sept 2012 - 10.55pm -- CLOSED**

I tried rmunoz idea with some tweaking. It worked like a magic. Thanks for rmunoz, with this I close this topic

```
awk '(NR - 62) % 217 == 0 || (NR - 152) % 217 == 0 || (NR - 153) % 217 ==0 {print $0;}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use patterns in AWK this way:

```
 awk 'NR == 62 || NR == 152 || NR == 153 || NR % (62+217) == 0 || NR % (152+217) == 0 || NR % (153+217) == 0 {print $0;}' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I am able to print line #62, #152,#153 but having problem in printing its next iteration which is #62+217, #152+217, #152+217, and so on. Tried awk '(NR == 62 || NR == 152 || NR == 153) && (((NR-62) % 217==0) || ((NR-152) % 217 ==0)|| ((NR-153) % 217==0)) {print $0;}' test.txt It does not work well too. Will continue to investigate

Comment: OK, I understood that you only wanted 62, 152, 152 and line % 127.
I am going to edit my answer to print line % (62+127), line % (152+127)...

Comment: I used your idea and did manipulation. The below is what I wanted. Thanks! You are an angel. awk '(NR - 62) % 217 == 0 || (NR - 152) % 217 == 0 || (NR - 153) % 217 ==0 {print $0;}' file.txt

Comment: Jajaja I am glad you got it.
AWK patterns are really powerful ;-)